# Download .zip file from FTP in java: which type of outputstream?

Tags: java, ftp

I wrote a śmall piece of java software that connects to an FTP server, and lists all the available files in the directory it connects to. Now, I would like to download 2 files. Both those files are .zip files, which brings me to the following question:
what type of outputstream should I use? FileWriter is for more adequate for "downloading" textfiles, right? Is FileOutputStream the best way to go when downloading archives, or does it make no difference?

Thanks in advance

Comment: OutputStream is fine. e.g.  OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile));

Comment: `FileWriter` is never "adequate" for anything, since it doesn't allow specifying an encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what type of outputstream should I use?

A `FileOutputStream`, or a `BufferedOutputStream` wrapped around it.

> `FileWriter` is for more adequate for "downloading" textfiles, right?

- `FileWriter` isn't an `OutputStream` at all, it is a `Writer`. It is for text data only.

> Is `FileOutputStream` the best way to go when downloading archives

It's the best way for downloading anything. Unless you **know** the data is text, which it certainly isn't in the case of a .zip file, there is no reason to use it.

> or does it make no difference?

It certainly does make a difference.